# Issue retrieving notifications - has been happening for 2 years now

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

On any Stack Exchange network site, I am having issues retrieving my notifications (done by clicking the Stack Exchange logo -> Notifications).

It displays an error with an option to dismiss. It's been occurring for around 2 years. There are no trace statements outputted to console either.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Okay I did a bit of investigating, and the success callback on the ajax request for the url `http://<siteurl>/notices/genuwine` is never being hit.

```
v = function (b, a, e, c, f) {
    var d = b.attr("id");
    if (u[d]) w();
    else {
        u[d] = !0;
        w();
        var g = function () {
            u[d] = !1;
            StackExchange.helpers.showErrorPopup($(".seContainer"), "An error occurred while loading - please try again.")
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: a,
            dataType: e,
            success: function (a) {
                u[d] = !1; // NEVER ENTERS THIS LINE
                a && (0 < a.length || f) ? c(b, a) : g()
            },
            error: g,
            complete: function () {
                $(".seContainer").removeSpinner()
            }
        })
    }
},
```

So I have a JSFiddle running with the exact parameters I am getting on the site: http://jsfiddle.net/acCzM/1/:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://meta.stackoverflow.com/notices/genuwine?userId=undefined",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (e) {
      console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("Error");        
    },
    complete: function () {
      console.log("Complete");
    }
});​
```

Comment: Yes. It occurs on any PC I visit the site from :P

Comment: So you have no specifics on a situation? Machine? Connection? It happens absolutely everywhere?

Comment: Hmm I was going to say it happens everywhere, but I just tried via Internet Explorer, and it worked. Interesting. However, I just tried it using Chrome on my Windows machine, and then again on my OSX Chrome Macbook, and they both failed.

Comment: The notifications box is loaded via AJAX, using the URL `http://<siteurl>/notices/genuwine`. Try `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/notices/genuwine` in a separate tab, does it give you an error there too?

Comment: Yes, the JSON response comes back well with all the notification data. No error contained within.

Comment: I'm looking through the JS now. I'll report back if I find anything

Comment: This consistently happens to me it I press the drop down too quicker (e.g. before the page has completely loaded)... Are you doing the same?

Comment: No I don't think so. Waiting 2s makes no difference. Waiting 20s makes no difference.

Comment: the funny thing is: this network is entirely based on Microsoft related technologies :D

Comment: Think I found the issue. Need sleep, but will post up what I know tomorrow.

Comment: Any update on this bug? Still bothering me - been unable to retrieve notifications for years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Looking into your requests, I don't see an issue.  Everything's coming back correctly (the `userId=undefined` bit is some old dead code, which I'm removing in the next build), but you aren't getting a callback apparently.</del>

<del>That sounds like a dodgy browser honestly, perhaps a dodgy extension.  Small chance that you've got a really messed up copy of jQuery cached, clearing cache might resolve the issue.</del>

<del>There's not really much we can do from our end though.</del>

OK, this turned out to be a JSON encoding issue.  A new version of the JSON library we're using fixes this, and will be pushed out with the next build.

Comment: I hear you. It's odd though, because it works for new StackExchange accounts, on the same PC and Chrome install. It's just my account that seems to be broken for me :(

Comment: Just doing a little debugging, I have noticed that my JSON isn't able to be parsed by jQuery and enters the parseError code. The JSON looks like this: https://gist.github.com/4151885

I can get it to work if I escape single and double quotes. Is it possible my account has dodgy data attached somehow?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra - Actually... it looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673226/c-how-to-print-time-in-format-20090810181754-811) has a dodgy title (there's some errant unicode in there).  That *should* be escaped properly though, might be related to [another JSON bug](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/ba114aa90f47daf2b3c936abf69b3f643a3e0282) I was hunting down earlier.  I'll slam together an up to date ServiceStack.Text build when I get in tomorrow and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: Kevin, that may be it, I'll try some more. I've currently got 2 accounts side by side (one works, one does not) and seeing where in the code it fails. The JSON for this other account looks very similar to mine. I did not notice the question you pointed out though.

Comment: @bugmenot - yeah, it's a JSON encoding bug; reproduced it locally.  The next ServiceStack.Text build will fix it, pinging some folks about whether we'll wait for an official release or pull in a dev build.